# Anycubic i3 Mega layer shifting

Tags: troubleshooting, calibration, anycubic-i3-mega, x-axis, layer-shifting

My Anycubic I3 Mega shifts every layer by a little distance making straight model lean to it's side by an angle.

For example, this white round blob should've been a straight up cylindrical shape, but it leans to the right for some reason.
[image: white blob instead of correct cylinder]

Don't look at dirty table, it was clean at the start of printing.

When I was printing this model, I prepared it with Cura 3.2.1 slicer.

What could be causing this problem? How it could be fixed?

**Update 1:** I've tried lowering print speed from 50 to 25 mm/s in Ultimaker Cura 4.4.1. It didn't help. After another test print it seems like it's an X axis problem.

[image: test print]
[image: closer look]

**Update 2:** Result after setting `print speed` to `10 mm/s` and `travel speed` to `50 mm/s` (same model, same ABS):
[image: Low speed => no shifting]
Even such slight change to `print speed` as `15 mm/s` still produces layer shifting.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Are the belts tight?

Comment: @0scar Hi! Thank you. Don't know if the belts are tight enough but not overly. How to know if they are?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a generic gcode file from Anycubic or with G-code produce by another slicer than the one you used? On mine, I use the Slic3r version by prusa (called PrusaSlicer as I had a Prusa printer before) and I just change (reduce) the speed (and some minor details like bed size) from Prusa i3 profile and it works correctly (no displacement between layer).

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I will investigate this possibility. Thanks.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu tried lowering print speed from 50 to 25 mm/s in Ultimaker Cura 4.4.1. Didn't help.

Comment: I've had seen similar issues where the gear on a stepper motor was loose and causing layer shifting but _only_ when travelling (due to the acceleration between print speed and travel speed). I spent a long time tweaking belts before it occurred to me to check the gears.

Comment: The massive reduction for good results hints that something with the carriage mounting seems to be defect. Can you tighten the belt on the Bed?

Comment: @Trish will try it, but all the belts seem to be tight enough.